# How can I delete the data I clicked in String[] Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-intent

I am getting data in String[] from another class with intent. I show the data I received in listview.  When I click the deleteshop button on the custom adapter, I want the data I clicked to be deleted from the String array. How can I do that?

My code;

```
        final ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list);

        final ArrayList<SubjectData> arrayList = new ArrayList<SubjectData>();

        final String[] cartList = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("saleData");

        arrayList.add(new SubjectData("", ""));

        final int cartListLength = cartList.length;
        int counter = 0;
        String lastItem = "";


        for (String e : cartList) {
            counter += 1;
            if (e == "" || e == null) {
                lastItem = cartList[counter-3];
                break;
            }

            String productPhoto = "";

            switch (e) {
                case "1 PC GREEN COLA x 10.00 TL":
                    productPhoto = "cc";
                    break;

                default:
                    productPhoto = "";
                    break;            }

          
        arrayList.add(new SubjectData(e,  productPhoto));;
        }
        arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);
        arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);
     

        final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

nextButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        nextButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_down);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        nextButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_up);
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrinterManagerActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("saleData", cartList);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                        //
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

SubjectData model class:

```
    String SubjectName;
    String Image;

    public SubjectData(String subjectName, String image) {
        this.SubjectName = subjectName;
        this.Image = image;
    }
```

Customadapter;

```
class CustomAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    ArrayList<SubjectData> arrayList;
    Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubjectData> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList=arrayList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final SubjectData subjectData=arrayList.get(position);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        
            TextView tittle=convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView imag=convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            ImageView 
            deleteshop=convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteshop);

            deleteshop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {                   
                        if (context instanceof SaleSummary) {
                            ((SaleSummary)context).deleteItem(position);

                            int selectedFromList = (int) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

                            String gettextdata = tittle.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(context, gettextdata""+"the product has been deleted
", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
             
            tittle.setText(subjectData.SubjectName);
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(subjectData.Image, "drawable",
                    context.getPackageName());

           

            imag.setImageResource(resourceId);

          

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }
```

listview design;

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="5dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/deleteshop"
        android:src="@drawable/negative"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp" ></ImageView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically removing data from an Array which is normal programming / data structure task.

You can run a for loop on cartList and when you encounter the item you wish to delete you can simply overwrite that item with next item until you get to end of list then you mark the last item as null.

```
for(int i ==0; i < cartList.length(); i++){
  if(cartList[i] == selectedItem){
    for(int j = i j < cartList.length(); j++){
      cartList[j] == cartList[j++];
    }
    // mark last item as null
    cartList[cartList.length()-1] = null;
    break;
  }
}
```

All you need now is a listener between your activity and adapter that will trigger the logic whenever user clicks on delete item on any item.

Comment: I could not delete data with this method. It didn't give an error, but the data deletion didn't happen. I had defined String[] cartklist= new String[100] in other activity. Most of these values ​​are empty. Could the code not work because of the cartlist.lengt part?